# NSTabView with background color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolor, nstabview

As discussed elsewhere, NSTabView does not have a setBackgroundColor method and subclassing NSTabView and using an drawRect to control it does no longer work - as it does not paint the top 10%, the bit just below the segmented control button.

Now I am a bit surprised by the amounts of work arounds I had to do solving this; see

- code: https://github.com/dirkx/CustomizableTabView/blob/master/CustomizableTabView/CustomizableTabView.m

and am wondering if i went down the wrong path. And how to do this better & simpler:

- The NSSegmentStyleTexturedSquare seems to yield me a semi-transparent segmented Control. Which means I need to do extra work to hide any bezel lines (line 240, 253).

  - is there a better way to do this ? I.e. negate its transparency ?
  - or is there a way I can use the actual/original segmented choise button ?
- I find that the colours I need - like the [NSColor windowBackgroundColour] are not set to anything useful (i.e. that one is transparent) -- so right now I hardcode them (lines 87, 94).

  - Is there a better way to do this ?
- I find I need a boatload of fluffy methods to keep things in sync ( line 128, 134, etc).

  - can this be avoided ?
- I find that mimicking the cleverness on rescaling means I need to keep a constant eye on the segemented Control box and remove/resize it. And even then - it is not quite as good as the original

  - is there a better way to do this than line 157 -- i.e. hear about resizing ? Rather than do it all the time ?
- The segementControl fades dark when focus is removed from the window - unlike the real McCoy.

  - can that easily be prevented ? is there a cheap way to track this ?
- Or is this the wrong approach - and should I focus on just a transparent hole here - and let the NSTabViewItem draw a background ? But in any case - then I still have the issue with the Segemented COntrol box - or is there than a way to make that be the default again.

  - when trying this - I get stuck on the top 20-30 pixels being drawn in the 'real' windows background colour - which is 'transparent' - and hence the colour will not run all the way to the top or behind the segment bar and up to the bezel - but instead stop some 8 pixels below the bottom of the segment controls.

Feedback appreciated - as this feels so far off/suboptimal for such a simple things -- 
Thanks a lot. Brownie points for hacking/forking the github code :) :) :) As a line of running code says more than a thousand words.

Dw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSMTabBarControl is probably the best workaround for you. I have created several custom tab views, but cocoa does not play well with this control. PSMTabBarControl has been updated to support Xcode 4. https://github.com/ciaran/psmtabbarcontrol

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background color of its underlying CALayer?  (Make it a layer-backed view, if it isn't already, by setting wantsLayer = YES.)

Comment: Hmm - tried that (see above github link, https://github.com/dirkx/CustomizableTabView/commit/bfbd5aeecaf13c65611d221a31cb644ed48108d4#diff-7d6a9b4a9a691023219e9dc3082910e6) - the settings to plain.XXX. And no cookie.

Comment: What was drawsBackground set to?  Was the tab view's type NSNoTabsNoBorder?  Are you sure the NIB was even loaded by the time applicationDidFinishLaunching was called?

Comment: Sure( and moving the code to setColour does not change behaviour). The issue is still that the background 'escapes' the well of the contentview of the tabview.

Comment: In that case, I'd probably create a generic NSView, set it to want a layer, set the layer's background color to what you want, and either position your tab view inside that layer or on top of it.  Or am I not understanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: The problem is that each individual tab item is drawn in a subview that's inset from the NSTabView. The NSTabView frame is too big, the tab item view frame is too small and leaves the gap mentioned in the original question. There would be no way to position a background NSView precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation can tolerate some fragility, a very simple and quick approach is to subclass `NSTabView` and manually adjust the frame of the item subviews. This gives each item a seamless yellow background:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    static const NSRect offsetRect = (NSRect) { -2, -16, 4, 18 };

    NSRect rect = self.contentRect;

    rect.origin.x += offsetRect.origin.x;
    rect.origin.y += offsetRect.origin.y;
    rect.size.width += offsetRect.size.width;
    rect.size.height += offsetRect.size.height;

    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

A future change in the metrics of `NSTabView` would obviously be a problem so proceed at your own risk!