# How to create custom NSStepper and NSTabView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstabview

I want re-draw these two controls, but I can not find the method to do that, anyone can give me idea to do that?

I have found some app has re-draw these controls, you can look the screenshot.
the first one is `NSStepper`, the second one is `NSTabView`,the `NSTabViewItem` is also be re-drawed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Subclass most of the GUI classes, if you need to customize.

For NSTabView, this is one of the class where you have to do a lot of thing yourself.

You have to draw yourself ( using beziers path )

Need to implement many methods of  NSView & NSResponder for drawing and event handling.

Kindly check these links :

[NSTabView with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090641/nstabview-with-background-color)

http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html

https://github.com/aaroncrespo/WILLTabView/