# Hide scrollers while leaving scrolling itself enabled in NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, swift, appkit, nsscrollview

I'd like to hide the `NSScroller`s of `NSScrollView`. I'm aware of the methods `setHasHorizontalScroller:` and `setHasVerticalScroller:`. However, if I disable the scrollers, scrolling in that direction gets disabled as well. I'd like to only hide the scrollers while maintaining the possibility to scroll. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to do this by doing:

```
[labelsScrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
[[labelsScrollView horizontalScroller] setAlphaValue:0];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is still working on macOS 10.13.4 with Swift. I did need to set the `.scrollerStyle` to `.overlay` for it to work though. For some reason with `.legacy` the "background" of the scrollbar is still drawn.

Comment: Scroller is not visible, but still can receive touches :0

Answer (score 8):

The trick of setting `alphaValue` to `zero` has issue as invisible scroller still receives touches. Here is what we did in order to solve this (Swift 4).

```
class InvisibleScroller: NSScroller {

   override class var isCompatibleWithOverlayScrollers: Bool {
      return true
   }

   override class func scrollerWidth(for controlSize: NSControl.ControlSize, scrollerStyle: NSScroller.Style) -> CGFloat {
      return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude // Dimension of scroller is equal to `FLT_MIN`
   }

   public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
      super.init(frame: frameRect)
      setupUI()
   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: coder)
      setupUI()
   }

   private func setupUI() {
      // Below assignments not really needed, but why not.
      scrollerStyle = .overlay
      alphaValue = 0
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
private class TabBarScrollView: NSScrollView {

   private func setupUI() {

      borderType = .noBorder
      backgroundColor = .clear
      drawsBackground = false

      horizontalScrollElasticity = .none
      verticalScrollElasticity = .none

      automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = false
      horizontalScroller = InvisibleScroller()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.hasHorizontalScroller == true {
  collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.horizontalScroller?.scrollerStyle = .overlay
  collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.horizontalScroller?.alphaValue = 0.0
} else {
  print("horizontalScroller")
}
```

Make sure horizontal scroller is selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for an answer to this as well since setting `hasVerticalScroller = false` disables trackpad scrolling for me. In the meantime, my horrible hack is to use the following in my NSScrollView subclass:

```
self.hasVerticalScroller = true
self.scrollerInsets.right = -999999
```

The scroller is technically visible, it is just way off the edge of the view. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [NSScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

```
[scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:NO];
```

this method doesn't disable scrolling.

If you still do not want to use that method you can also:

```
[scrollView setHorizontalScroller:nil];
```

Comment: my English ( Thank you, rokjarc.

Comment: Doesn't work. Setting either of these actions results in a scroll view that no longer responds to scroll events for that direction.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution from sam's answer above:

```
[myNSScrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[_myNSScrollView setScrollerInsets:NSEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -99999)];
```

The scroller will be hidden even during the scrolling process.